# Why Soundness holds also when he underlying vocabulary contains = in Derivational LK Soundness and Completeness?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the book: Logical Foundations of Proof Complexity (S.Cook), we have a proof for the Derivational Soundness and Completeness of LK assuming that the underlying vocabulary does not contain =. In this proof is said that the soundness direction holds also when he underlying vocabulary contains =.

[Theorem in the mentioned book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8zJt.png)

My question is, why the soundness holds with = and completeness does not?

Comment: As you can see from II.3.10 Completeness holds (as expected) also for the language with $=$. I'm not familiar with Cook & Nguyen's proof, but IMO the reason may be that the details of the proof are so different (more technical "complexity" needed to manage the case with $=$) that the authors prefer to split the proof in two.